# How to add arbitrary custom CSS to a Wordpress Block Theme using Site Editor?

Tags: css, block-editor, full-site-editing

When using a [Block Theme](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/block-themes/) then you can use the [Site Editor](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/site-editor/), accessible via: Wordpress Dashboard > Appearance > Editor. — Introduced in [Wordpress 5.9](https://wordpress.org/documentation/wordpress-version/version-5-9/) on 2022-01-25.

1. **Site Editor > Styles** (right side panel) allows you to tweak global **Styles** (typography, colors, layout) and certain selected attributes of **Blocks**. And thereby alter the CSS which eventually comes out of the [Styles Engine](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/styles/#global-styles).
2. **But how can I add arbitrary custom CSS to a Wordpress Block Theme?** Analog to classical themes with [customizer](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customizer/) support (introduced in [WordPress 3.4](https://wordpress.org/documentation/wordpress-version/version-3-4/) 2012-06-13) where you can go to: Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > **Additional CSS**.

Answer (score 1):

In [WordPress 6.1.1](https://wordpress.org/news/2022/11/wordpress-6-1-1-maintenance-release/) (released 2022-11) this is not possible in the UI. **But good news**:

In Wordpress 6.2 (to be released somewhen March 2023) this will be possible! Was introduced as an experimental feature in [Gutenberg 14.8 from 2022-12](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/12/22/whats-new-in-gutenberg-14-8-21-december/#Add-custom-CSS-rules-for-your-site)  (see [video](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/12/22/whats-new-in-gutenberg-14-8-21-december/#Add-custom-CSS-rules-for-your-site) )

**It works like this:**

1. Wordpress Dashboard > Appearance > Editor
2. Open the Styles panel
3. In the panel you got a new section "Additional CSS".
4. There you can paste arbitrary CSS. (and its immediately rendered on the canvas nearby)

[image: How to add arbitrary custom CSS to a Wordpress Block Theme using Site Editor]

Comment: This is coming to core in 6.2 this month.

Comment:  Good news! Thanks for the info!

Comment:  Integrated that release plan into my answer.